# How can I disable all external url Google in Wordpress backend?

Tags: wp-admin, google

At certain places google.com blocked. When opening the Wordpress backend requires a very long time. Do you have a suggestion about a function to disable external url google such as Google Fonts,Google Analytics and Google APIs?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Just a tip, do not ask for plugins, recommendations for plugins and themes are off topic here :-)

Comment: check this answer [Disable Google Fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006452/how-to-close-google-font-reference-in-wordpress)